# Como obtener resultado de ejecutar un script en webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview-android

Hola estoy teniendo problemas al obtener el resultado html al ejecutar un script, ya que cuando cargo mi página y esta termina de cargar lo ejecuto y este muestra un mensaje similar a un toast y modifica el HTML, me gustaría obtener ese mensaje o la modificación del html o saber si se ejecutó satisfacoriamente. esto lo hago en siguiente código.

```
browser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "alert");
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            browser.loadUrl("javascript:alert.alert(WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(newWebForm_PostBackOptions(\"C tl00$cphPage$formProduct$ctl00$productDetail$btnAddCar\", \"\", true, \"ValidateProduct1347301\",  \"\", false, true)))");
        }});
```

Saludos

Comment: Cargas un mensaje y lo deseas obtener? A que modificacion del HTML te refieres?

Comment: Le explico en la página web se visualiza un contador con la cantidad de productos añadidos y este está en 0, al ejecutar un script este adiciona un producto y en la pantalla se muestra un mensaje flotante el cual dura un segundo aproximadamente, y luego aumenta el contador, lo que deseo es obtener ese mensaje flotante o verificar si el contador aumento. Saludos y gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

** *Talvez llegue un poco tarde pero a alguién le puede ser de utilidad.*

Para empezar la forma que utilizas para ejecutar codigo JS no es correcta para tu caso de uso.

Para esto es mejor utilizar el metódo [`evaluateJavascript (String script, ValueCallback<String> resultCallback)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)), él cual te pertime evaluar codigo JavaScript y executar código Java en función del valor retornado.

Otra observación es que el codigo que provees es que tu metódo implementado `public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)` nunca ejecuta la siguiente linea de codigo, la cual es necesaria para que funcione correctamente la implementación de `WebviewClient`.

```
super.onPageFinished(view, url);
```

Por ultimo, dentro del metódo `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)` no estas utilizando el Webview pasado como parametro al mismo metódo, si no que estas llamando la instancia del Webview que estas configurando lo cual ocasionará problemas.

Habiendo dicho esto tu codigo pasaría de esto:

```
browser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "alert");
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            browser.loadUrl("javascript:alert.alert(WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(newWebForm_PostBackOptions(\"C tl00$cphPage$formProduct$ctl00$productDetail$btnAddCar\", \"\", true, \"ValidateProduct1347301\",  \"\", false, true)))");
        }});
```

A algo como esto:

```
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // importante para poder ejecutar JS

browser.setWebViewClient(
        new WebViewClient() {
             @Override
             public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                 super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                String scriptEvaluar = // Script que define una función anónima autoejecutable la cual utiliza manejo de Excepciones para saber si todo el codigo JS se ejecutó exitosamente
                    "(function(){ " +
                                    "try {" +
                                        "alert(" +
                                            "WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(" +
                                                "newWebForm_PostBackOptions(" +
                                                    "'C tl00$cphPage$formProduct$ctl00$productDetail$btnAddCar', " +
                                                    "'', " +
                                                    "true, " +
                                                    "'ValidateProduct1347301', " +
                                                    "'', " +
                                                    "false, " +
                                                    "true" +
                                                ")"+
                                            ")" +
                                        ");" +
                                        "return true; " +                   
                                    "} catch (e) { " + // si ocurre una excepción el valor devuelto es false
                                        "return false; " +
                                    "} " +
                                "}" +
                    ") ();";

                 view.evaluateJavascript(scriptEvaluar, value -> { // expresión lambda que se ejecuta cuando se evalua el script
                             String resultado = "¿Codigo ejecutado con éxito? => " + value;
                             Log.d("WebView", resultado); // imprimir mensaje en consola
                             Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), resultado,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // mostrar Mensaje en GUI
                         }
                 );

             }
        }
);
```

Cabe resaltar que le dí un formato más legible y entendible a tu codigo.

*No olvidar adaptarlo a tus necesidades. Saludos!*